# Linq to SQL Weird Error

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am getting this error: `Could not format node 'Column' for execution as SQL`

When I am trying to make any anonymous type:

```
 select new
 {
     NounTypeName = nt.Name,
     Attributes =
     (
         from a in nt.NounTypeAttributes
         group a by a.Attribute into g
         select new { 
             NounTypeId = nt.NounTypeId, 
             Key = g.Key + " (" + g.Count() + ")", 
             NounTypeAttributeId = 
                 (from i in g select i.NounTypeAttributeId)
                  .Take(1).SingleOrDefault(), Count = g.Count()
         }
     )
 });
```

The problem comes when I add a `NounTypeId` property in the anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

Might I recommend loading your NounTypes and NounTypeAttributes into local memory, and then shaping?

```
CustomDataContext myDC = new CustomDataContext();
DataLoadOptions myOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
myOptions.LoadWith<NounType>(nt => nt.NounTypeAttributes);
myDC.LoadOptions = myOptions;

List<NounType> theNounTypes =
(
  from nt in myDC.NounTypes
  where //TODO filterExpression
  select nt
).ToList();

var queryResult = from nt in theNounTypes
  select new
...
```